# Nativescript - How to disable the return key to add newline in editable TextView

Tags: javascript, android, ios, textview, nativescript

[Official Documentation of Nativescript TextView](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_text_view_.textview)

According to the link above, there's an attribute called `returnKeyType`. But it's not working...

Is there any other proper way to set the returnKeyType? Or simply disable the `newline` when pressing the `return` key?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, this is a suitable approach for your case

```
let tv = <TextView>page.getViewById("tv");

tv.on("blur", () => {
   tv.text = tv.text.replace(/\n/gm, " ");
})
```

Comment: Hi @Wilson, thank you! This answer is clean & acceptable!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [open feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4315), but there is also a [workaround](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4315#issuecomment-306385670) that should work for now, just use `1` instead of `3` in example.

Comment: Hi @Manoj! Thanks for the help! I think {N} should update their documentation for not confusing developers since the `returnKeyType` is not working in editable <TextView>. BTW, the solution you provided works well but for my case, I need it auto text wrapping for overflow-x, just like what <TextView> behave, just disable return key to add `newline`, any possible approach?

Comment: I believe docs can be updated only for supported / implemented features. Github could be the better place for issues, workarounds etc., Return key should work on textview, but it will still add new line as it's default behaviour until you apply the workaround described in the Github issue. Also new line is different from text wrap, so your text view should still wrap text in Android.

Comment: For iOS you might have to cusotmize the delegate method here - https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/ui/text-view/text-view.ios.ts#L66 to replace the new line character. If you prefer a simple cross platform solution, then listen for textChange events and if new line chars found, then set text back on textview after removing new lines.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I found an acceptable answer in the reply below. Cheers ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it, if you only need one line, why don't you use TextField instead of TextView? TextField does exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Hi @Sow, thank you for your reply! I'm so sorry the question did confuse you. 
What I need is setting the input to be like `textWrap='true'` in <Label> but the `textWrap='true'` seems not working in <TextField>, or do I miss any important attrs? Cheers

Comment: Mate, I am afraid that `textWrap` doesn't work with TextField. And `returnKeyType` doesn't work with TextView. So you've to go with the workaround mentioned in the reply above.

Comment: Yeah, so I think {N} should update their documentation for not confusing developers. Sadly, the workaround mentioned by @Manoj also doesn't behave like `textWrap`